# Qt app crashing on linking with DLL made using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll

Before asking the problem, I would like to tell that i have thoroughly searched for the answer here. None of them seems to address my issue.
Problem:
I have created a simple C++ DLL file using Qt after following steps given [on the Qt wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application) the problem is though the DLL is created and I have linked it to my Qt widget app, the app crashes on creating the object of the file.
Here I am posting the source code and the qdebug output

libraray Qt pro

```
QT       += core gui widgets

TARGET = myLib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        mylib.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mylib.h \
        mylib_global.h 

unix {
    target.path = /usr/lib
    INSTALLS += target
}
```

mylib.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_H
#define MYLIB_H

#include "mylib_global.h"

class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT MyLib
{

public:
   MyLib();

   int add(int x, int y);
   int sub(int x, int y);

};

#endif // MYLIB_H
```

mylib_global.h

```
#ifndef MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
#define MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#if defined(MYLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
#endif // MYLIB_GLOBAL_H
```

mylib.cpp

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include<QDebug>

MyLib::MyLib()
{
}

int MyLib::add(int x, int y)
{
    qDebug()<<"Adding";
    return x+y;
}

int MyLib::sub(int x, int y)
{
   return x-y;
}
```

Now the app

myWidgetApp.pro

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = myWidgetApp
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui
INCLUDEPATH += "D:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\myLib"

LIBS += "D:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\build-myLib-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\myLib.dll"
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include"mylib.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyLib lib;
    lib.add(1,2); 
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Now the application output
    `D:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\build-myWidgetApp-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\myWidgetApp.exe` crashed.

I am using Windows 7 Professional with Qt 5.9.1

Comment: copy `myLib.dll` beside your executable and try again

Comment: your path contains spaces It's better to use Add library dialog to add external libraries, just right click on your .pro file and choose add library

Comment: Have you run it through Dependency Walker to see if any other DLLs are missing?

Comment: @saeed i tred that but dint work

Comment: @saeed i also tried by keeping the library in such path not consisting space but it dint work

Comment: @MrEricSir i tried that and placed the dll in that folder i also included those dll in qt .pro file but dint work

Comment: When dose your problem ocuures at runtime or compiletime

Comment: In your .pro file add -L after LIB+=

Comment: @saeed thanks a lot :) adding -L worked

Comment: @saeed actually it ran first time i added -L, next time it gave error D:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\myApp\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MyLibC1Ev'  D:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\myApp\main.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5MyLib3subEii'

Comment: @saeed so removed -L and recompiled and strangely now its again working, don't know whats going on here

Comment: Are you running qmake every time you try?
Try using `LIBS += "LD:\Gurushant\My Other Side Projects\Making dll Files\build-myLib-Desktop_Qt_5_9_1_MinGW_32bit-Release\release\ -lmyLib`. It should always work.

Comment: Ya am running qmake every time and i even rebuild every time, anyway now the problem is no more. But if add -L at the beginning of path it will throw error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far after doing a lot of trial and error, the best way to include the library is to

```
INCLUDEPATH += (Your_Path)
DEPENDPATH += (Your Path)

(if your target path is win32)
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L(path) -l(lib_file_without_dot_dll)
```

- don't use space after -L